# Integral of a log with complex phase in terms of special functions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

This is a longshot, but can anyone see a special function that the following integral can be written in terms of?
\begin{align}
\int_0^{1/a} \mathrm{d}x \:(\text{ln}(a x))^{-i p} e^{-ikx}
\end{align}
A similar problem yielding a similar integral leads to a Gamma function (so that was my first thought as I searched the integral tables), but haven't been able to see a nice substitution or similar to manipulate this integrand into such a nice form. Any insights would be appreciated!